# Where is MinimalCD for 20.04 LTS?

Tags: command-line, system-installation, 20.04, minimal-install

When I go to http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/ I don't find mini.iso in the path installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ - where is it located nowadays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrong directory. See  [installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/)